# How to get updates for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

I recently stopped being able to get updates for Ubuntu 12.04. Using Update manager, I now have 105 updates (almost 300mb) waiting, but everytime I click "Install", a window comes up with this message:

```
CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20140722.2)' is required
```

I don't know why I need to do this, but I downloaded an .iso version of that, put it in my DVD/CD drive, and still get the same warning window. I've tried updating from a terminal (sudo apt-get update) and, after a long list of archives I get this warning at the end (and no updating):

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Anybody know what's going on? This has just been happening over the last few weeks.

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list; tail +1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` in your question, by editing it.

Comment: Why can't you get 14.04? It's supported until 2019, and support for 12.04 is now ending.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Ubuntu installation has the Ubuntu 14.04 CD/DVD listed as one of its sources, which if you're using 12.04 is strange, to say the least.

Is it possible these were left behind after a failed attempt to upgrade or something?

You'll need to find the specific lines in either `/etc/apt/sources.list` or the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that refer to this CD and comment them - and only them - out.  Then re-run `sudo apt-get update`.

If you're having this problem, though, then there may also be other issues in your APT sources.  You should only have lines referring to "precise" (Ubuntu 12.04) and not "trusty" (Ubuntu 14.04).

Note that the warning you received about duplicate sources.list entries seems to be unrelated to your problem, and not a serious problem (other than generating this warning), but could be a further indication that you - or something - has messed up your sources.list file(s).